# IP tables - how to configure connections into my compuer

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a problem with following thing:
Foreign connection is connection initialized not by my computer.

I would like to accept only foreign connection such that port is 22 or from interval [1000, 1100]

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accepting port 22

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

For ports 1000-1100

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1000:1100 -j ACCEPT
```

if you enter these lines into `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file on your linux machine and restart iptables service with `service iptables restart` command, you should be good to go.

Comment: You'll also need to allow ESTABLISHED connections.

Comment: @Celada What does you mean exactly?

Comment: @MelBruslan , Is it possible to accept only these connections that I initialized them  ? ( at the same time I would like to preserver above setting - special ports

Comment: what do you mean by _connections that I initialized them_ ?

Comment: I mean I would like to connect to other computer for example (my firewall should accept it). However, when other computer would like to **start** connection to me I am going to reject this.   Exception is connections from ports as above.

Comment: Let me understand this correctly. you just want to start an ssh connection to the outside world and nothing else from your computer and want to accept incoming connections between ports 1000 and 1100. Nothing else. is that right ? This did not sound like a good plan to me. Since you control the computer you are on, you can do whatever you want to do and, unless specified so, iptables doesn't get in your way. If there are other on the system and you want to block them from accessing anything but outgoing ssh connections, that is something else. Maybe you should explain your case in more detail

Comment: No no, I want to accept incoming connections between ports 1000 and 1100 and on port 22. Every other connection shuold be rejected. When it comes to outcoming connections (I start connection) it should be accecpted every connection (all)

Comment: In that case, you do not need any additional lines in the iptables file. It is not putting any restriction to outgoing connection, provided that there aren't any suck blocks in your existing configuration.

Comment: Could you show me these commands ? I am newbie in that.